# .obj file data imported for used in Remesh Modifier

Tags: import, remesh

I am using Blender software to voxelized a model. Hence, I am using the block function provided in the Remesh Modifier of this software. However, I am still struggling to understand how this block function is used to import model. In my case, I am using the .obj file. When I wanted to see the type of faces that exist in the model, I unticked the wireframe option to view it.

[image]

So, it presented the model like this. I assumed that the faces that exist in the model are not triangular faces. However, when I study on the source code under dualcon_c_api.cpp, there are dealing with triangular faces.

[image]

Hence, I want to know what is the relationship between the imported model and the triangular faces. Does the Model Reader convert .obj file to triangulated faces to be processed using the Remesh Modifier function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to ask "Close-voter" to explain the reason in a comment to help understand what is wrong with the Q. Thank you

Comment: Hai, can I have an idea about this?